# Suddenly all apps are crashing and after that it return to the lock screen Ubuntu 22.04 lts

Tags: 22.04, crash

I'm not able to do anything . Everything getting crash and return back to the lock screen. Previous day it works fine and today when I turn on the laptop and open Chrome it stack and crash. It takes too much time to reboot and start.

New year new issue . Pls kindly help.